# Socket.io server in the browser

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, socket.io

I want to use `socket.io` server in the browser.

Why do I need this? I have a difficult real-time app which connected through websockets, but I want to manually test it through web page (send & receive the signals). How can I do that?

P.S. Packages like `mockSocket` aren't feet to my needs. I don't need the mock, I need the tab in the browser :)

Comment: Why can't you just run node locally?

Comment: Hm, I want this process be runned just by opening a browser, without any commands

Comment: I wish I was stronger in `socket.io` to make a comment like this, but I think it's not possible in the way you are attempting.  The limitation I think you will run into is the lack of any ability for an in-browser JavaScritp engine to let you listen to traffic on a port (I understand that is what web sockets are for, but I think there are limitations for turning that into a local web server), perhaps someone more knowledgeable will explain a workable solution though.

Comment: you can't run a server from a client. you can turn the client box into a server also, but you can't do that from the browser.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I start a socket.io/websocket server in browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42039634/can-i-start-a-socket-io-websocket-server-in-browser)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is no way to run websocket server in the browser now.